# How do I scroll right in puppeteer 5.1.0 using mouse.wheel?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a grid on this page. The last column is off screen to the right. I want to read the header cell text.
I saw this snippet at
https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.1.0&show=api-class-mouse

So I ran the code below in cucumber/puppeteer. There were no errors but nothing happened in the browser. So how do I scroll to the right using this feature or any other way.

I can't use querySelector... to get the header because the selectors don't exist until the column is visible. Please advise.

```
async function scrollRight() {
   await this.page.mouse.wheel({ deltaX: 2500 })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `scrollRight()` function should have a part where **the mouse hovers over the right column.** In the linked example there is a [`page.mouse.move(x,y)`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.1.0&show=api-mousemovex-y-options) which should be applied in your case as well.

To get the X Y coordinates of your column you can use [`elementHandle.boundingBox`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.1.0&show=api-elementhandleboundingbox) puppeteer function. With a simple formula you can position the cursor exactly to the center of the column.

E.g.:

```js
async function scrollRight() {
  const elem = await page.$('.last-column');
  const boundingBox = await elem.boundingBox();
  await page.mouse.move(
    boundingBox.x + boundingBox.width / 2, // x
    boundingBox.y + boundingBox.height / 2 // y
  );

 await page.mouse.wheel({ deltaX: 2500 });
}
```

To check visibility of the column you can use [`page.waitForSelector`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.1.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options)'s `visible: true` option, which waits for the element to be visible, i.e. to not have `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` CSS properties. It defaults to `false`, so if it caused problems in your use case that it was not visible it may help.

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.last-column', {
  visible: true,
});
```

Comment: got following error: Cannot read property 'boundingBox' of null. Don't know how to enter code in a comment so will put in next comment

Comment: `  async function scrollRight() {

    const elem = await this.page.$('.last-column');
    const boundingBox = await elem.boundingBox();
    await this.page.mouse.move(
        boundingBox.x + boundingBox.width / 2, // x
        boundingBox.y + boundingBox.height / 2 // y
    );
} `

Comment: You are getting this error because the `.last-column` CSS class is not available on the actual page (I just gave that name as an example). You should look for the exact selector of the last column that you want to scroll.